# A place with illustrations of Gemara Sukkah?

Tags: talmud-gemara, talmud-bavli, sukkah, masechet-sukkah, shas

The beginning of Sukkah (4a/4b) describes different scenarios where platforms are built alongside the three walls of the Sukkah. I am having a very tough time picturing how they are built and therefore a tough time understanding the Gemara.

Does anyone know of any online source where they have physical pictures or illustrations of these Sukkahs to help me better understand it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the Peirush Chai on Masechta Succah [here](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=28062&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=16260104403533522&pagenum=15) - it is a really helpful sefer to best illustrate the cases that come throughout the masechta.

Comment: It is also available on HebrewBooks [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47554&pgnum=15).

Answer (score 4):

Both the Mesivta and Veshinantam Gemaras have color plates in the back that illustrate these and many other things throughout the masechta. (The ones from Veshinantam are also available on the [Daf Yomi Portal](http://daf-yomi.com), under ללמוד ולהבין > תמונות עזר. You can also go to http://daf-yomi.com/Search.aspx?publisher=14 and see the complete list of their illustrations, then filter by masechta and so forth.)

As far as those particular cases on 4a, I've actually seem Gemaras that have the illustrations on the standard Gemara page rendered instead (in the same locations) in 3-D. One of them is the [ש"ס וילנא החדש published by Mesores Hashas](https://textratz.co.il/product/%D7%A9%D7%A1-%D7%95%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%90-%D7%94%D7%97%D7%93%D7%A9/); another is the Mesivta.

Comment: here is the appropriate link - https://files.daf-yomi.com/files/klali/lilmod/suka_pics/suka_004.pdf

Comment: Note the pictures on 4a were originally part of Rashi, not in the Gemara. https://seforimblog.com/2021/07/sukkah-4a-whats-wrong-with-this-picture/